# django / python - regular expression

Tags: python, regex, django, date, django-templates

I am trying to write a [django custom template tag and filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/) to display the date according to the language code of the user. Searched SO and Google a lot, but am unable to find an example or reference.

I am having difficulties with the regex (at least that what I think I have to code here) to change the passed date format from mm/yyyy to yyyy.mm.

Here is my template tag code:

```
{{ variable_name|date:'m/Y'|format_date_display:variable.language_version.language_code }}
```

The above code will pass the date as mm/yyyy (as the value) as well as the two character language code (as the arg) ie: en, fr, bg, ar, de, etc.

Here is my customised_template_tags.py code:

```
@register.filter(name='format_date_display')
    def format_date_display(value, arg):
    .......

    #  yyyy-mm (dash separator and year first).
    elif arg in ('eu', 'en-CA', 'fr-CA', 'lt', 'sv', 'zh-CN', 'zh-TW'):
        #  TODO: change the date format from mm/yyyy to yyyy-mmm.
        return value.replace("/", '-')

    ......
```

**How do I write the regex for the new date display as yyyy-mm?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working off the value of the date format is mm/yyyy (12/1999), try this:

```
@register.filter(name='format_date_display')
    def format_date_display(value, arg):
    .......

    #  yyyy-mm (dash separator and year first).
    elif arg in ('eu', 'en-CA', 'fr-CA', 'lt', 'sv', 'zh-CN', 'zh-TW'):
        # the line below will change the date format from mm/yyyy to yyyy-mmm.
        value = value[3:] + value[2:3] + value[0:2]
        return value.replace("/", '-')

    ......
```

In the Python language the above syntax (**value = value[3:] + value[2:3] + value[0:2]**) is know as slicing.